# Why do we specify "weak" when testing in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have noticed that the recommended way to test a view controller in XCode with Sencha testing is via instantiating it with

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) MyMainViewController* mainViewController;
```

Why not just

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyMainViewController* mainViewController;
```

?

Comment: Where did you see this usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readwrite is not strictly necessary, as it is the default.  As for strong vs weak, the main reason to use weak is to avoid a reference cycle (i.e. two objects that have strong references to each other so they will never be deallocated).

Answer (score 1):

As @borrrden mentioned, weak references are useful when try to avoid retain cycles.

If you are looking into weak references, I would highly recommend reading [this post](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) by Mike Ash. It is important to understand the difference between zeroing weak references and non-zeroing weak references.